# how to do k means clustering on sift features in matlab?

Tags: k-means, sift

I want to perform k-means clustering on sift features which is in the form of a 509X508 matrix.I got a code for k-means clustering from mathworks. But i don't know how to give input for the algorithm.
Pls help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/stats/kmeans.html).

`IDX = kmeans(X,k)` partitions the points in the `n-by-p` data matrix `X` into `k` clusters. . Rows of X correspond to points, columns correspond to variables. `kmeans` returns an n-by-1 vector `IDX` containing the cluster indices of each point.